# NSURL Encoding in ObjC

Tags: cocoa

How to do URL encoding in NSURL ?

Thanks

Comment: It is easier now with iOS 7: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423545/objective-c-iphone-percent-encode-a-string/20271177#20271177

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:

```
NSString* escapedUrlString =
   [unescapedString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                        NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

However, in my experience, this method isn't quite perfect (in handling some reserved characters), and in many cases I needed to use the variant:

```
 NSString * escapedUrlString =
  (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
    NULL,
    (CFStringRef)unescapedString,
    NULL,
    (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
    kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );
```

Comment: +1, but with a reminder that `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` returns a string with a +1 retain count, so you must `release` it when you're done.

Comment: You saved my day @notnoop

Answer (score 6):

**stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:** has some [problems with URL arguments](http://jongampark.wordpress.com/2009/03/21/bugs-in-stringbyaddingpercentescapesusingencoding/).

In conjunction I use **gtm_stringByEscapingForURLArgument** from [Google Toolbox for Mac](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/) for URL arguments.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
NSString *response = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[url  stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:STRING_ENCODING_IN_THE_SERVER]] 
                                                      encoding:STRING_ENCODING_IN_THE_SERVER 
                                                         error:&error];
```