# How to achieve URL encoding in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am developing an application in which I need to encode URL. I tried using http://simonwoodside.com/weblog/2009/4/22/how_to_really_url_encode/ and 
`[NSString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]]` but its not working out for me. Is there any alternate URL encoder class for iphone like java?
How to achieve it?? Thanks in advance...

Comment: try NSUTF8StringEncoding if it works. But if you want encoding for removing space in URL than the method you are using is fine

Comment: @Javal Nanda I tried NSUTF8StringEncoding also it does not work.It dont encode certain special characters(like ";:)

Comment: @BoltClock thats what I wrote above.. NSUTF8StringEncoding dont encode some special characters(All the special characters needs to be encoded in my app).So whats the alternate way to match java's URL encoder class?

Answer (score 3):

**Try the following for URL encoding :**

```
NSString *url= [(NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)originalpath, NULL, CFSTR(";:"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8) autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423545/objective-c-iphone-percent-encode-a-string) to find your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following for URL encoding:

```
`NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.abc.com/parsexml.aspx?query=%@", [searchBar.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];`
```