# how to get white spaces in NSString using web server

Tags: objective-c

```
hai ,
```

i created one chat application by using web service, it works well. when i gave some space between the characters that is going to be quiting.. same issue is arises when i use the special characters. sometime when i give space the program can't quit. but the input message can't inserted into the web server. what method i wish to use for solving this issue.. thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is this method

```
NSString* escapedString = [string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

this will remove all the withe spaces of a string, and encode it correctly so it can be send through the server

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do [percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) of the string in client side before sending it to server, Otherwise server unable to recognise those characters.

For example: To distinguish a space character you have to use %20

If yo want to learn how to do these operation you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423545/objective-c-iphone-percent-encode-a-string)