# stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString not working as expected

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Having a problem.  Here's my code:

```
Latitude = [TBXML textForElement:lat]; //Latitude & Longitude are both NSStrings
Longitude= [TBXML textForElement:lon];
NSLog(@"LAT:%@ LON:%@",Latitude,Longitude);
NSString *defaultURL = @"http://api.wxbug.net/getLiveWeatherRSS.aspx?ACode=000000000&lat=+&long=-&unittype=1";
newURL = [[defaultURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" 
                                                        withString:Latitude]
                                    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" 
                                                        withString:Longitude];
NSLog(@"%@",newURL);
```

And here's the output:

```
LAT:-33.92 LON:18.42 
http://api.wxbug.net/getLiveWeatherRSS.aspxACode=000000000&lat=18.4233.92&long=18.42&unittype=1
```

As you can see, something strange is happening to the appending code.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before replacing the longitude, the string is

```
http://....&lat=-33.92&long=-&...
                ^           ^
```

The system sees that there are two `-`, and thus both of them will be replaced by the latitude.

---

You should use a more descriptive string to replace with, e.g.

```
NSString *defaultURL = @"http://....&lat={latitude}&long={longitude}&unittype=1";
newURL = [defaultURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{latitude}" 
                                               withString:Latitude];
newURL = [newURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{longitude}" 
                                           withString:Longitude];
```

or simply use `+stringWithFormat:`.

```
NSString* newURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://....&lat=%@&long=%@&...",
                                              Latitude, Longitude];
```

Comment: Thank you, it all comes clear now. :)  I will do as you suggested and change the placeholder to a more clear value.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's where we started:

```
url = @"http://...?ACode=000000000&lat=+&long=-&unittype=1"
Latitude = @"-33.92"
Longitude = @"18.42"
```

Then you replaced all occurrences of `@"+"` with `@"-33.92"`:

```
url = @"http://...?ACode=000000000&lat=-33.92&long=-&unittype=1"
```

Then you replaced all occurrences of `@"-"` with `@"18.42"`. **Note that there are two '-' characters; one after `lat=` and one after `long=`**. The one after 'lat' is there because the string you pasted in had a `-` in it.

```
url = @"http://...?ACode=000000000&lat=18.4233.92&long=18.42&unittype=1"
```

Thus, your final result.

Answer (score 2):

@KennyTM, BJ Homer, and madmik3 are correct.  Your value is getting replaced twice.

However, you should *technically* be building your URL in a totally different manner:

```
NSMutableDictionary *query = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[query setObject:@"000000000" forKey:@"ACode"];
[query setObject:Latitude forKey:@"lat"];
[query setObject:Longitude forKey:@"long"];
[query setObject:@"1" forKey:@"unittype"];

NSMutableArray *queryComponents = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *key in query) {
  NSString *value = [query objectForKey:key];
  key = [key stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
  value = [value stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

  NSString *component = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", key, value];
  [queryComponents addObject:component];
}

NSString *queryString = [components componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];

NSString *fullURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.wxbug.net/getLiveWeatherRSS.aspx?%@", queryString];
NSURL *newURL = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURLString];
```

(ignoring the efficacy of `-stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` for now)

The reason this is better is that according to the HTTP specification, [the keys and values in the query of the URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) should be [URL encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url_encoding).  Granted, you're only encoding numbers for simple keys.  But if that ever changes, you URL might break.  (The flaw with this method is that it only allows a single value per key, and the HTTP spec allows you to specify multiple values.  For the sake of simplicity, I've left that out)

There are also some issues on using `-stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`.  For more information on that, check out [Objective-c iPhone percent encode a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423545/objective-c-iphone-percent-encode-a-string).

Comment: Dave, awesome advice.  For now I don't think I need to implement it, but I'll keep it in mind.  Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Your LAT is negative. So the - gets replaced twice.