# NSURLRequest returning null

Tags: objective-c, nsurl, nsurlrequest

Someone knows why I'm getting null in this code?

```
NSURLRequest *requisicao = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                               [NSURL URLWithString:URLAddress]];
```

When I debug this line and preview the content of this variable, I receive null -
`"<NSURLRequest (null)>"`

My URLAddress is a request for a JSON service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's most likely null because URLAddress contains characters that need to be percent-escaped (which is what the URLWithString method needs).

Try using `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`:

```
NSURLRequest *requisicao = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
    [NSURL URLWithString:
        [URLAddress stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                        NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
```

However, see [this answer by Dave DeLong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412431/losing-a-when-converting-from-nsurl-to-nsurlrequest/5412596#5412596) which points out limitations of `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` and alternatives to it.