# Objective-C and Swift URL encoding

Tags: swift, objective-c, nsstring, urlencode

I have an `NSString` like this:

```
http://www.
```

But I want to transform it to this:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fwww.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I have an encrypted string like `ùÕ9y^VêÏÊEØ®.ú/V÷ÅÖêú2Èh~` - none of the solutions below seems to address this!

Answer (score 336, accepted):

To escape the characters you want is a little more work.

Example code

> iOS7 and above:

```
NSString *unescaped = @"http://www";
NSString *escapedString = [unescaped stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"escapedString: %@", escapedString);
```

NSLog output:

> escapedString: http%3A%2F%2Fwww

The following are useful URL encoding character sets:

```
URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet  "#%<>[\]^`{|}
URLHostAllowedCharacterSet      "#%/<>?@\^`{|}
URLPasswordAllowedCharacterSet  "#%/:<>?@[\]^`{|}
URLPathAllowedCharacterSet      "#%;<>?[\]^`{|}
URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet     "#%<>[\]^`{|}
URLUserAllowedCharacterSet      "#%/:<>?@[\]^`
```

Creating a characterset combining all of the above:

```
NSCharacterSet *URLCombinedCharacterSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" \"#%/:<>?@[\\]^`{|}"] invertedSet];
```

Creating a Base64

In the case of Base64 characterset:

```
NSCharacterSet *URLBase64CharacterSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"/+=\n"] invertedSet];
```

> For Swift 3.0:

```
var escapedString = originalString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:.urlHostAllowed)
```

> For Swift 2.x:

```
var escapedString = originalString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
```

Note: `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` will also encode UTF-8 characters needing encoding.

> Pre iOS7 use Core Foundation
>   Using Core Foundation With ARC:

```
NSString *escapedString = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
    NULL,
   (__bridge CFStringRef) unescaped,
    NULL,
    CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]\" "),
    kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
```

Using Core Foundation Without ARC:

```
NSString *escapedString = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
    NULL,
   (CFStringRef)unescaped,
    NULL,
    CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]\" "),
    kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

Note: `-stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` will not produce the correct encoding, in this case it will not encode anything returning the same string.

`stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding` encodes 14 characrters:

> `#%^{}[]|\"<> plus the space character as percent escaped.

testString:

```
" `~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}[]|\\:;\"'<,>.?/AZaz"
```

encodedString:

```
"%20%60~!@%23$%25%5E&*()_+-=%7B%7D%5B%5D%7C%5C:;%22'%3C,%3E.?/AZaz"
```

Note: consider if this set of characters meet your needs, if not change them as needed.

RFC 3986 characters requiring encoding (% added since it is the encoding prefix character):

> "!#$&'()*+,/:;=?@[]%"

Some "unreserved characters" are additionally encoded:

> "\n\r \"%-.<>\^_`{|}~"

Comment: Also note you can use NSString's `-stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` method.

Comment: This code also leaks memory unless you use a `__bridge_retained` cast under ARC, or call `CFRelease` at some point on the return value from `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`.

Comment: Ah yes, now I remember the funky `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` behaviour. It only encodes '&' and '=' or something ridiculous like that.

Comment: Under ARC the initial answer does leak and the suggestion by @Mike is correct, I have added alternatives for use under ARC.

Comment: also under ARC you would need to set the bridge for the unescaped string: 
...
(__bridge CFStringRef) unescaped,
...

Comment: According to [RFC1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) you would need to encode additional characters as well. So although this does answer the OP's question, it has limited usefulness as a general-purpose URL encoder. For example, it doesn't handle non-alphanumerics such as a German umlaut.

Comment: Maybe for more usability, should the solution contain the space and quote characters? Something like `CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]\" ")`

Comment: This doesn't work (for iOS 7 part). This doesn't convert & into %26.

Comment: Create the character set you need from an `NSString` with `characterSetWithCharactersInString`, take the inverse with `invertedSet` and use that with `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters`. For an example see this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24552028/451475).

Comment: [The Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/WorkingwithURLEncoding/WorkingwithURLEncoding.html) says:

`Important: Although the NSString class provides built-in methods for adding percent escapes, you usually should not use them.`

Answer (score 24):

It's called [URL encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).  More [here](http://madebymany.com/blog/url-encoding-an-nsstring-on-ios).

```
-(NSString *)urlEncodeUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding {
    return (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
           (CFStringRef)self,
           NULL,
           (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",
           CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));
}
```

Comment: This would be a lot more useful if some content from the links you posted were included in the answer.

Comment: `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes()` is deprecated. Use `[NSString stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:]` instead.

Answer (score 7):

This is not my solution. Someone else wrote in stackoverflow but I have forgotten how.

Somehow this solution works "well". It handles diacritic, chinese characters, and pretty much anything else.

```
- (NSString *) URLEncodedString {
    NSMutableString * output = [NSMutableString string];
    const char * source = [self UTF8String];
    int sourceLen = strlen(source);
    for (int i = 0; i < sourceLen; ++i) {
        const unsigned char thisChar = (const unsigned char)source[i];
        if (false && thisChar == ' '){
            [output appendString:@"+"];
        } else if (thisChar == '.' || thisChar == '-' || thisChar == '_' || thisChar == '~' ||
                   (thisChar >= 'a' && thisChar <= 'z') ||
                   (thisChar >= 'A' && thisChar <= 'Z') ||
                   (thisChar >= '0' && thisChar <= '9')) {
            [output appendFormat:@"%c", thisChar];
        } else {
            [output appendFormat:@"%%%02X", thisChar];
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

If someone would tell me who wrote this code, I'll really appreciate it. Basically he has some explanation why this encoded string will decode exactly as it wish.

I modified his solution a little. I like space to be represented with %20 rather than +. That's all.

Comment: Original code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423545/objective-c-iphone-percent-encode-a-string/3426140#3426140

Comment: what is [self UTF8String] ?

Comment: @yuchaozh this is a function that you put inside a category of NSString.  So, self is NSStirng and [self UTF8String] returns, assumingly, its string in UTF8 format.

Answer (score 4):

```
 NSString * encodedString = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NUL,(CFStringRef)@"parameter",NULL,(CFStringRef)@"!*'();@&+$,/?%#[]~=_-.:",kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );

NSURL * url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[@"address here" stringByAppendingFormat:@"?cid=%@",encodedString, nil]];
```

Comment: release encodedString and url.
this code is about encode parameter. To encode whole address pass string instead of "parameter".

Comment: This worked for me... encoded even the & character that I was having issues with.

Answer (score 4):

This can work in Objective C ARC.Use CFBridgingRelease to cast a Core Foundation-style object as an Objective-C object and transfer ownership of the object to ARC .See [Function CFBridgingRelease](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/1587932-cfbridgingrelease) here.

```
+ (NSString *)encodeUrlString:(NSString *)string {
return CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes
                         (kCFAllocatorDefault,
                          (__bridge CFStringRef)string,
                          NULL,
                          CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]"),
                          kCFStringEncodingUTF8)
                         );}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I use. Note you have to use the `@autoreleasepool` feature or the program might crash or lockup the IDE. I had to restart my IDE three times until I realized the fix. It appears that this code is ARC compliant.

This question has been asked many times, and many answers given, but sadly all of the ones selected (and a few others suggested) are wrong.

Here's the test string that I used: `This is my 123+ test & test2. Got it?!`

These are my Objective C++ class methods:

```
static NSString * urlDecode(NSString *stringToDecode) {
    NSString *result = [stringToDecode stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" "];
    result = [result stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return result;
}

static NSString * urlEncode(NSString *stringToEncode) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *result = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                NULL,
                (CFStringRef)stringToEncode,
                NULL,
                (CFStringRef)@"!*'\"();:@&=+$,/?%#[]% ",
                kCFStringEncodingUTF8
            ));
        result = [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@"+"];
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift iOS:

Just For Information : I have used this:

```
extension String {

    func urlEncode() -> CFString {
        return CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
            nil,
            self,
            nil,
            "!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
            CFStringBuiltInEncodings.UTF8.rawValue
        )
    }

}// end extension String
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *str = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                             NULL,
                             (CFStringRef)yourString, 
                             NULL, 
                             CFSTR("/:"), 
                             kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

You will need to release or autorelease `str` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Google implements this in their [Google Toolbox for Mac](https://github.com/google/google-toolbox-for-mac). So that's a good place to peak how they're doing it. Another option is to include the Toolbox and use their implementation.

Checkout the implementation [here](https://github.com/google/google-toolbox-for-mac/blob/master/Foundation/GTMNSString%2BURLArguments.m#L23). (Which comes down to exactly what people have been posting here).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am doing this in swift.

```
extension String {
    func encodeURIComponent() -> String {
        return self.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
    }

    func decodeURIComponent() -> String {
        return self.componentsSeparatedByString("+").joinWithSeparator(" ").stringByRemovingPercentEncoding!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did on Swift 5:

```
func formatPassword() -> String {
    
    var output = "";

    for ch in self {

        let char = String(ch)

        switch ch {

            case " ":
                output.append("+")

                break

            case ".", "-", "_", "~", "a"..."z", "A"..."Z", "0"..."9":

                output.append(char)

                break

                default:

                print(ch)

                let unicode = char.unicodeScalars.first?.value ?? 0

                let unicodeValue = NSNumber(value: unicode).intValue

                let hexValue = String(format: "%02X", arguments: [unicodeValue])

                output = output.appendingFormat("%%%@", hexValue)

                }

            }
    
    return output as String
}
```

Then I called this function where I defined my password.

Answer (score -1):

//use NSString instance method like this:

```
+ (NSString *)encodeURIComponent:(NSString *)string
{
NSString *s = [string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
return s;
}

+ (NSString *)decodeURIComponent:(NSString *)string
{
NSString *s = [string stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
return s;
}
```

remember,you should only do encode or decode for your parameter value, not all the url you request.

Comment: stringByReplacingPercentEscapeusingencoding: only escapes & and = :-(

Comment: Correct, so things like + are not encoded, when they need to be. So dont use the above answer

Answer (score -8):

```
int strLength = 0;
NSString *urlStr = @"http://www";
NSLog(@" urlStr : %@", urlStr );
NSMutableString *mutableUrlStr = [urlStr mutableCopy];
NSLog(@" mutableUrlStr : %@", mutableUrlStr );
strLength = [mutableUrlStr length];
[mutableUrlStr replaceOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"%3A" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, strLength)];
NSLog(@" mutableUrlStr : %@", mutableUrlStr );
strLength = [mutableUrlStr length];
[mutableUrlStr replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"%2F" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, strLength)];
NSLog(@" mutableUrlStr : %@", mutableUrlStr );
```