# Trim any illegal characters from NSURL before writing to disk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsurl

I would like to write a string to an `NSURL` which may contain characters such as `/` or `:`, which are not supported by the file system. Is there any convenience method to trim these characters? Or maybe a reference containing all illegal characters, so that I can write such a method myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be it's better just to escape them with something like this:

```
NSString *unescaped = @"http://www";
NSString *escapedString = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
    NULL,
   (CFStringRef)unescaped,
    NULL,
   (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
    kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

NSLog(@"escapedString: %@",escapedString);
```

as it [stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086584/objective-c-url-encoding)?

Or you can just strip ! * ' ( ) ; : @ & = + $ , / ? % # [ ] characters, if you wish so.
Look [here for a list of reserved characters](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/uri-spec.html).

Comment: I now replace the `!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]` characters. Thanks