# NSString encode some particular string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

Which is the correct way to transform `à` in `%C3%A0`. I found a lot of solution but nobody of them works

Thanks

Comment: why do you want to display `à` as `%C3%A0` ? Please post what have you tried as well, thanks

Comment: It's called "URL encoding". Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086584/objective-c-url-encoding