# Convert URL to correct format

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdata, nsurl

I have been trying to fix this for the past few hours and I cannot seem to get anything working. My question is straightforward, I need to convert some strings that are being inputted to a URL so that it correctly sends the spaces and special characters to the receiving server.

I have 3 strings: `setFirstLast.text`, `emailAddress.text`, and `visitingTest.text`. I need to convert them into something that prints like: `John%20Smith` instead of `John Smith`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

`[string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`

to get the desired result. `string` is the object containing your original text and `NSUTF8StringEncoding` is one of many encoding options available.

Answer (score 0):

Here, $url1 is your original url.

```
$url1 = "http://X.X.X.X/print/postToDB.php?namestamp=John Smith&emailstamp=john@example.com&visitingstamp=Bob Clark";
```

You could do:

```
$url2 = urlencode($url1);
//prints: http%3A%2F%2FX.X.X.X%2Fprint%2FpostToDB.php%3Fnamestamp%3DJohn%20Smith%26emailstamp%3Djohn%40example.com%26visitingstamp%3DBob%20Clark%0A
```

or

```
$url3 = str_replace(' ','%20', $url1);
//prints: http://X.X.X.X/print/postToDB.php?namestamp=John%20Smith&emailstamp=john@example.com&visitingstamp=Bob%20Clark
```

Does this help?

Comment: Mike, thanks for the quick response. I should have been more clear in my question. I'm trying to encode the string as it leaves the iOS device, not after it arrives at the server. My apologies. I will revise the question.

Comment: If this is in terms of objective-c, you may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086584/objective-c-url-encoding.

Comment: YES! That worked. I can't believe I didn't come across that article. Much appreciate Abishek! Thank you so much.