# UIWebView doesn't load page with the stringWithFormat

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

Here is My problem. 
I was trying to create programmatically an UIWebView and it worked perfectly, but when I **tried to change url from simple NSString to NSString[stringWithFormat] it goes wrong**. UIWebView just don't want to load the page, but in Safari(Mac) page load and display content.

**My code** :

```
NSString *APP_ID = @"4000";
NSString *PERMISSIONS = @"audio, films, friends";

NSString *full_url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://google.com?a=%@&b=%@", APP_ID, PERMISSIONS];

NSLog(full_url);
NSURLRequest *loginRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:full_url]];

UIWebView *loginWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
loginWebView.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:loginWebView];
[loginWebView loadRequest:loginRequest];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formatted URL is will turn out to be "http://google.com?a=4000&b=audio, films, friends".  I think you need to URL encode the second parameter to `stringWithFormat:`.  See one answer on how to do that here: [Objective-C and Swift URL encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086584/objective-c-url-encoding)

Comment: Thank You. I just remove whitespaces and now page is displaying!