# Why doesn't CFStringEncodings have UTF8 in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, utf-8, swift

I am trying to create a percent encoded string in Swift so I can safely send text as a `GET` request. I found some Objective C code which I am trying to convert to Swift. I've written the following Swift code:

```
CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(nil, 
    CFStringRef(encodedString), nil, 
    CFStringRef("/%&=?$#+-~@<>|\\*,.()[]{}^!"), 
    kCFStringEncodingUTF8)
```

There is no `kCFStringEncodingUTF8` in Swift ... If you right click the `CFStringEncodings` source you see there is a million things in there but no UTF8. I don't understand. How can I use the UTF8 string encoding in this situation?

**EDIT :** I found a way to encode a string but I still don't understand what happened to `kCFStringEncodingUTF8`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The UTF-8 string encoding is defined as

```
enum CFStringBuiltInEncodings : CFStringEncoding {
    // ...
    case UTF8 /* kTextEncodingUnicodeDefault + kUnicodeUTF8Format */
    // ...
}
```

and can be used as

```
let orig = "a/b(c)"
let escaped = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(nil, orig, nil,
    "/%&=?$#+-~@<>|\\*,.()[]{}^!",
    CFStringBuiltInEncodings.UTF8.rawValue)
println(escaped)
// a%2Fb%28c%29
```

As mentioned by @Zaph in a comment, `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` might
be easier to use:

```
let charset = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "/%&=?$#+-~@<>|\\*,.()[]{}^!").invertedSet
let escaped = orig.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(charset)
```

or use one of the pre-defined character sets from 
[Creating a Character Set for URL Encoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet).

Comment: Instead of using toRaw() we now have to use: CFStringBuiltInEncodings.UTF8.rawValue

Answer (score 2):

`kCFStringEncodingUTF8` has been replace in Swift with: `UTF8`.

There is a new `NSString` method added in iOS7 that takes a character set and a number of specialized character sets have been added and of course you can create specialized character sets. There is very little reason to use `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` any more. See this: [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8086845/451475)