# Unable to convert NSString to NSURL

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, nsurl

I'm using following code to get the NSURL from NSString but I always get NSURL as null :

```
NSString *CFURL = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,(CFStringRef)[assetURL absoluteString], NULL, CFSTR("!$&'()*+,-./:;=?@_~"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8));

NSString *instagramString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"instagram://library?AssetPath=%@&InstagramCaption=%@", (NSURL *)CFURL, strInstagramCaption];

NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:instagramString];
```

Comment: The question is lacking enough information to answer, in particular missing are: `assetURL` and `strInstagramCaption`. Also instead of using `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` See this: [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8086845/451475) for using `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:`.

Comment: @zaph is wrong ! Already answered here:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30566795/create-nsurl-using-assetpath

Comment: Nice link the a correct solution and a reference to another answer. Wondering what part of the comment is wrong?

Comment: Great complete blog post on sharing a video to Instagram: [horison blog](http://blog.horizon.camera/post/102273431070/video-share-objc-ios-instagram)

Answer (score 1):

`NSURL` does not natively support the instagram protocol. [Here are the supported protocols.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165-BCICJDHA)

> The URL loading system provides support for accessing resources using
> the following protocols:
>
> File Transfer Protocol (ftp://)
>
> Hypertext Transfer Protocol (http://)
>
> Hypertext Transfer Protocol with encryption (https://)
>
> Local file URLs
> (file:///) Data URLs (data://)

As stated in the documentation, you will have to create a [custom protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/CookiesandCustomProtocols/CookiesandCustomProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i-CH10-SW2).

Comment: Can you please help me convert the `instagramString` into `instagramURL` ?

Comment: While this is true for the URL loading system it is not true for just creating a URL, this will create a URL: `NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://library?AssetPath=qqq"];`