# Create NSURL using AssetPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, instagram-api

Using UIImagePickerController, I'm able to get the Asset Path for a Media like `assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=2A2CE6C9-C178-4395-977B-E6F159BF6D5E&ext=MOV`.

```
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"instagram://library?AssetPath=%@&InstagramCaption=%@",[referenceURL absoluteString], strInstagramCaption]];
```

Now, I want to convert this Asset Path into NSURL to pass it into following code block :

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you a question. When you do this, do you find that the Instagram app sometimes goes to the image/video which was added before? So in other words it opens up the second to latest one for some reason?

Comment: No, the above instagramURL opens Home tab of Instagram App

Comment: Well I have been testing it and it opens the Photo/Video uploader.

Comment: Can you please share the whole code ?

Comment: I am basically using the code from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27702493/4657588

Comment: I want `assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=B202E621-FCCB-48BA-817C-8DF9605ED799&ext=JPG` path from `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/ABADEDFA-FDEE-47BA-A7F5-575AAA40F937/Documents/InstaImage.png` path. Please help

Comment: Ok I added an answer, I think it may solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is the way how you should convert asset path to valid `NSUrl`:-**

```
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"instagram://library?AssetPath=%@&InstagramCaption=%@",[assetURL absoluteString],caption]stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
    }
```

Referred from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26367862/instagram-video-iphone-hook)

Comment: `.percentEscape ` is custom property ?

Comment: Yes... it is. Updated the answer.

Comment: Can you please share the whole code to share to share a Video to Instagram?

Comment: No, that's against the rule of SF. Your objective was to Create NSURL using AssetPath which is already answered here.Try yourself, then if still you find problem then share your code here or raise another question , Will surely help you then.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you would have used `UIImagePickerController` to select a photo from the library or to bring up the camera? Either way you must be making use of the following delegate method:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

}
```

Well in that method, you can get the URL of the asset and then pass that to AVAsset framework for the asset URL and then put that in the Instagram URL.

```
(NSURL *)[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
```

Use the above code to obtain a URL for the image in the `imagePickerController` delegate method. You can then pass that to AVAsset.

**Update**
This is also a useful link to look at, its explains how to use `UIImagePickerController` - http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-camera-iphone-app/.

Hope this helps :)