# How to create a custom NSCharacterSet?

Tags: swift, urlencode, nscharacterset

I’m using `CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed` to add percent-encoding to a String.

Some characters are not encoded the way I expected (i.e. `&` and `?` are not changed). That being said, I had the idea to build a custom `CharacterSet`, ideally based on an existing one.

What’s the best approach to do so?

Comment: Look at `NSMutableCharacterSet` that should give you possibility to play with existing `NSCharacterSet`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The most typical way to create a new character set is using
`CharacterSet(charactersIn:)`, giving a `String` with all the characters of the set.

Adding some characters to an existing set can be achieved using:

```
let characterSet = NSMutableCharacterSet() //create an empty mutable set
characterSet.formUnionWithCharacterSet(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
characterSet.addCharactersInString("?&")
```

or in **Swift 3+** simply:

```
var characterSet = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
characterSet.insert(charactersIn: "?&")
```

For URL encoding, also note [Objective-C and Swift URL encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086584/objective-c-url-encoding)

Comment: Works perfectly fine, thank you! But when I try to add "ÄÖÜäöü" it hasn't any effect?

Comment: @mrtn.lxo You will have to add more context to your comment. How are you adding them? What are you doing later with the character set?

Comment: I simply used myCaracterSet.addCharactersInString("Ä")

Answer (score 8):

You can try my method:

```
let password = "?+=!@#$%^&*()-_abcdABCD1234`~"

// Swift 2.3
extension NSCharacterSet {
    static var rfc3986Unreserved: NSCharacterSet {
        let mutable = NSMutableCharacterSet()
        mutable.formUnionWithCharacterSet(.alphanumericCharacterSet())
        mutable.addCharactersInString("-_.~")
        return mutable
    }
}

let encoding = password.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.rfc3986Unreserved)

// Swift 3
extension CharacterSet {
    static var rfc3986Unreserved: CharacterSet {
        return CharacterSet(charactersIn: "-_.~").union(.alphanumerics)
    }
}

let encoding = password.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .rfc3986Unreserved)

Print：
original -> ?+=!@#$%^&*()-_abcdABCD1234`~
encoding -> %3F%2B%3D%21%40%23%24%25%5E%26%2A%28%29-_abcdABCD1234%60~
```

rfc3986:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986
[image: reference]