# NSURL: Escape Backslash using NSCharacterSet

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, ios9, nsurl, backslash

This may be a duplicate question, but I have checked all over and can't find a working answer for iOS9. -stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding has been deprecated. I need to use -stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters

Below is the string that needs the backslashes escaped so that the API can authenticate the session and return a response.

```
NSString *base = @"http://domain.com/interface/?end=imember";
NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet];
NSString *key = [@"&client_key=KOB3N6KX9JXF2MRPO5U.BRFYM7TYVE\/16KIJVXZA6R7H\/1LD1K\/JYIYG7IZP2HA7NUYOVNT3CJG==&token=SGD7E9B29TQ.8HIITZ37XW3GLK5OGLZNLCDM=" stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:set];
```

The standard URL Character sets don't escape the backslashes, I have tried them all:

```
URLUserAllowedCharacterSet
URLPasswordAllowedCharacterSet
URLHostAllowedCharacterSet
URLPathAllowedCharacterSet
URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet
URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet
```

Please if someone could assist, I am rather new to development. Is it possible to create a custom allowed set which includes the backslash?

EDIT:

This is what the url should look like:

```
http://domain.com/interface/?end=imember&client_key=KOB3N6KX9JXF2MRPO5U.BRFYM7TYVE\/16KIJVXZA6R7H\/1LD1K\/JYIYG7IZP2HA7NUYOVNT3CJG==&token=SGD7E9B29TQ.8HIITZ37XW3GLK5OGLZNLCDM=
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact solution for you answer is below.I got it from [Zaph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086584/objective-c-url-encoding).That is the better answer than other answer.

```
NSString *unescaped = @"http://domain.com/interface/?end=imember"];
NSString *escapedString = [unescaped stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"escapedString: %@", escapedString);
```

URL Encoding Character Sets are

```
URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet  "#%<>[\]^`{|}
URLHostAllowedCharacterSet      "#%/<>?@\^`{|}
URLPasswordAllowedCharacterSet  "#%/:<>?@[\]^`{|}
URLPathAllowedCharacterSet      "#%;<>?[\]^`{|}
URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet     "#%<>[\]^`{|}
URLUserAllowedCharacterSet      "#%/:<>?@[\]^`
```

Comment: When I use URLHostAllowedCharacterSet this is the result:

Comment: `&client_key=KOB3N6KX9JXF2MRPO5U.BRFYYGM7TYVE%2F16KIJVXZHUA6R7H%2F1LDD1K%2FJYIY22G7IZP2HA7NUYOVJWEHNT3CJG==&token=SGD7XXL ... LZNLCDM=` it has replaced the backslashes with Percentage sign

Comment: Welcome brother:-)