# Adapting JSON for ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I use JSON for implementing Facebook in an app and I'm just making my code ARC-friendly. However, when I make lines such as this one

```
CFStringAppendCharacters((CFMutableStringRef)json, &uc, 1);
```

become

```
CFStringAppendCharacters((__bridge CFMutableStringRef)json, &uc, 1);
```

my app is no longer able to pull my photo albums (I allow the user to log into Facebook and I then display his albums in order for him/her to get a picture to later use in the app).

This is the entire code that is not appreciated by ARC - (could anyone give me a hint how to bridge it please?)

```
NSString* escaped_value = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                              NULL, /* allocator */
                              (CFStringRef)value,
                              NULL, /* charactersToLeaveUnescaped */
                              (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                              kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

Does anyone know how I could port the JSON framework for ARC use?

Comment: Which JSON framework? And why not just exclude this code from ARC?

Comment: Or, if you're going ARC then why not just use NSJSONSerialization? It's only 4.3 support you'll lose.

Comment: I tried excluding it from ARC but then my Facebook API crashes. If I'm going to use NSJSONSerialization, do I need to do the parsing myself or is it all there already? I wouldn't necessarily like to rewrite functionality I already have. How does NSJSONSerialization work?

Comment: Check and see if the latest Facebook SDK (which comes with the SBJSON library built into it) is ARC compatible.

Comment: NSJSONSerialization does the parsing for you, and is built into Cocoa. It's probably a good choice.

Comment: Made a call to NSJSONSerialization and it worked like magic :) Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see in your comment that you just decided to go with `NSJSONSerialization`, that will definitely work. But to actually answer your question.

Using the `__bridge` cast is easy when you think about the memory management involved.  `__bridge` just casts without doing any memory management operations for you; `__bridge_transfer` also casts, but it decrements the retain count of the object being casted. So with that in mind, your function call can be broken down like so:

```
CFStringRef originalValue = (__bridge CFStringRef)value;// Only __bridge required because ownership not changing
CFStringRef escapeChars = (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]";// __bridge not required for string literal
CFStringRef escaped_CFString = CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, originalValue, NULL, escapeChars, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);// returns a CFStringRef that YOU own.
NSString *escaped_value = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)escaped_CFString; // __bridge_transfer tells the compiler to send a release call to escaped_CFString.
```

Now that you see what's happening you can safely stack the calls like this:

```
NSString* escaped_value = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,(__bridge CFStringRef)value,NULL,(CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

Note that this method is still not that reliable. A more complete solution can be found in [Dave DeLong's answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3426140/927947).