# IOS not encoding plus(+) sign in x-www-form-urlencoded POST request?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

I am using the following code,

```
NSString *jsonD = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"rawJson=%@",[fbUserInfo jsonUTF8String]];
NSData *myRequestData = [jsonD dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                           cachePolicy:policy timeoutInterval:20.0];

[ request setHTTPMethod: @"POST" ];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [myRequestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[ request setHTTPBody: myRequestData ];
```

In this code I have the date `2013-06-29T18:33:17+0000`. The problem is that my server receiving date as  `2013-06-29T18:33:17 0000`. See the space. I don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just because you specify the encoding header does not mean the `NSURLRequest` will actually *perform* said encoding.

The `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` function can URL-encode your strings for you.

If you don't care about the encoding and just want to send simple strings, I suggest you skip the encoding entirely and use the "text/plain" content type.

Another option would be to use JSON instead of form encoding ("application/json"). JSON is much easier to use, both on the server side and on the client side. Cocoa has builtin support for JSON.

**EDIT**: Now that I read your code again, I see that you name your variable suggesting that the data is already JSON. If so, the solution is to use the `"application/json"` content type and make sure the server understands and decodes this properly.

Comment: I need x-www-form-urlencoded encoding? Is this same? I will try and let you know

Comment: Not necessarily, if you need to form-encode objects (i.e. arrays, dictionaries, and whatnot) you need to encode them as key-value pairs as well. For simple strings the escaping should be enough.

Comment: This is not a simple JSON. It coming from 3rd part side. I need to correctly encode this as x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: Thanks. CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes works for now.

Comment: Yep, this is the right answer. Either use JSON data with `application/json` header, or URL encoded data with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header. Mixing the two will result in no good.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to have the `' '` -> `'+'` substitution, you need to do it on your own.

See: [Objective-c iPhone percent encode a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423545/objective-c-iphone-percent-encode-a-string/3426140#3426140) for the code to do the conversion.

---

**Update**

OK, based on your comment, here is some additional information. Based on old handling of query strings, `'+'` characters are turned into `' '` characters.

It was enshrined into old JavaScript, CGI, and PHP handing of URLs.

Microsoft even has a [buggy example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring.aspx) demonstrating it.

You can avoid the problem by always converting `'+'` to `'%2B'` and `' '` to `'%20'`.

Comment: I am sending plus from client. I need to get + on server. I need simply this

Comment: @user960567 I updated my post with some information as to why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

The [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) library solves it thusly:

```
static NSString * AFPercentEscapedQueryStringPairMemberFromStringWithEncoding(NSString *string, NSStringEncoding encoding) {
    static NSString * const kAFCharactersToBeEscaped = @":/?&=;+!@#$()~',*";
    static NSString * const kAFCharactersToLeaveUnescaped = @"[].";

    return (__bridge_transfer  NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)string, (__bridge CFStringRef)kAFCharactersToLeaveUnescaped, (__bridge CFStringRef)kAFCharactersToBeEscaped, CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));
}
```

Comment: Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: Yes, sorry that was kind of mean. My point is that a third party lib is not the solution to all problems. This does solves (I guess) the problem, but by avoiding it altogether. I didn't downvote though, as it does provide a solution to the problem :)

Comment: I agree; I was showing the implementation only as an example of how others have solved it, not to advocate for using that library _in toto_.

Answer (score 1):

As @Krumelur suggested,The `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` function can URL-encode your strings for you.
And Here is the code.

```
static NSString * CTPercentEscapedQueryStringValueFromStringWithEncoding(NSString *string, NSStringEncoding encoding) {
    return (__bridge_transfer  NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)string, NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)kCharactersToBeEscapedInQueryString, CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));
}
```

**And Complete solution**
: To get encoded url from parameters use below code.

```
/**
 get parameterized url from url and query parameters.
 */
+(NSString *)getParameterizedUrl:(NSString *)url withParameters:(NSDictionary *)queryDictionary
{
    NSMutableArray *mutablePairs = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString *key in queryDictionary) {
        [mutablePairs addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@", CTPercentEscapedQueryStringKeyFromStringWithEncoding(key, NSUTF8StringEncoding), CTPercentEscapedQueryStringValueFromStringWithEncoding(queryDictionary[key], NSUTF8StringEncoding)]];
    }

    return [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@?%@",url,[mutablePairs componentsJoinedByString:@"&"]];
}

static NSString * const kCharactersToBeEscapedInQueryString = @":/?&=;+!@#$()',*";

static NSString * CTPercentEscapedQueryStringKeyFromStringWithEncoding(NSString *string, NSStringEncoding encoding) {
    static NSString * const kCharactersToLeaveUnescapedInQueryStringPairKey = @"[].";

    return (__bridge_transfer  NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)string, (__bridge CFStringRef)kCharactersToLeaveUnescapedInQueryStringPairKey, (__bridge CFStringRef)kCharactersToBeEscapedInQueryString, CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));
}

static NSString * CTPercentEscapedQueryStringValueFromStringWithEncoding(NSString *string, NSStringEncoding encoding) {
    return (__bridge_transfer  NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)string, NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)kCharactersToBeEscapedInQueryString, CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));
}
```

And use in your code as

```
NSString *url = [self getParameterizedUrl:@"http://www.example.com" withParameters:self.params];
```

Note : params here is dictionary.