# Properly escaping characters for AFNetworking 2.0 URL string

Tags: ios, objective-c, escaping, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I have a api which needs to use a url string in order to work (wouldn't work with the normal NSDictionary request). The string I'm trying to use is

```
http://10.1.10.25:8181/config?param={"obj":["hours"]}
```

However, the following code which I used to escape the characters does not work. It returns a bad url error. What is the proper way to escape characters here?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://10.1.10.25:8181/config?param={\"obj\":[\"hours\"]}"];
// Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1000 "bad URL" UserInfo=0x8ca3780 {NSUnderlyingError=0x8ca6980 "bad URL", NSLocalizedDescription=bad URL}
```

Below is a picture of a working example using a online REST service.
[image: this works]

Comment: You need to encode the URL: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3426140/1445366  You may want to make your own AFNetworking request serializer so that you don't need to duplicate this logic outside of your networking stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you just need to encode your param like this:
`http://10.1.10.25:8181/config?param=%7B%22obj%22%3A%5B%22hours%22%5D%7D`

Comment: For the benefit of others: Only encode the query part, not the whole url string.