# Swift Error while NSURLSession.sharedSession()

Tags: json, parsing, swift

Currently i run into a problem i really don't understand, as its just a different string that should not change anything.

This one crashes my App

> https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/Jüjük?api_key=5c7d4d4f-f320-43d5-8647-643c9f6ee5de

This one works without any problems

> https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/smirknaitia?api_key=5c7d4d4f-f320-43d5-8647-643c9f6ee5de

Here is my Code:

```
    let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        if (error != nil) {
            println(error)
        } else {
            let jsoneResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary

            println(jsoneResult)

        }
    })

    task.resume()
```

It already crashes in `let task0 = session0.dataTaskWithURL(url0!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in`
With the Error Message:

> Thread1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Any clue what brings causes the error and how to fix it?

Comment: You have to encode Umlauts (and other non-ASCII symbols).

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20271177/1489885)