# iPhone: Try to send html code to a php script (but fail)

Tags: php, iphone, http-post

I am trying this for an iPhone app in Xcode:

- create html code for a website on the fly
- sending it to a php-script and getting the response with this code:


  `NSError * error = [[[NSError alloc]init]autorelease];

  NSURL * phpURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.mydomain.com/myscript.php?mywebsite= (...websitestring...) ];
  NSString * myResponse = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:phpURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];`

It does not work. It should not be a problem of the php code because when I replace the websitestring which contains the html code with "hello" or something, this is accepted. (the script then creates a file "test.html" with the content I sent.) But when I put html code in it, I always get the error:

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)" UserInfo=0x322ec10 {}

It seems that there are some things to consider when sending code to php?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you encode `websitestring` properly?

Comment: I think what he means is, have you URLEncoded the websitestring?

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, I would have never figured that. I encoded it following the answer from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748981/nsurl-encoding-in-objc and it works! Saved the evening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness: the advice to encode "websitestring" properly by rik was the solution.