# Convert NSString to a form passable in a HTTP POST request

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, escaping, http-post

Is there a simple way to escape a NSString so I can use it in a HTTP POST request?

I've tried `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`, but the following:

```
[@"~!@#$%^&*()-+\"'" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

gives me:

```
~!@%23$%25%5E&*()-+%22'
```

which is not usable in a HTTP POST query because the `&` is left unescaped; therefore the other end interprets whatever follows it as another argument.

Comment: Look up the URLEncoding category for NSString.  It looks like it is under MIT License and you can find it by searching "NSString+URLEncoding.m"

Comment: @Maudicus: thanks, that worked, I'm posting it as an answer for Googlers.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718429/creating-url-query-parameters-from-nsdictionary-objects-in-objectivec, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748981/nsurl-encoding-in-objc, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159341/nsstring-method-to-percent-escape-for-url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function, part of `NSString+URLEncoding.m`, does exactly what I need:

```
- (NSString *)encodedURLParameterString {
NSString *result = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                       (CFStringRef)self,
                                                                       NULL,
                                                                       CFSTR(":/=,!$&'()*+;[]@#?"),
                                                                       kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    return [result autorelease];
}
```