# How can i pass special character(like #,@,%,$) in NSRequestURL with GET method JSON Objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, nsurlrequest

How can I pass NSRequestURL like http://ww.a.com/Account/CheckValidUser?username=abc&password=abc123# through JSON with HTTP GET Method to server?. Passpword contain # chracter.
How i can send this with NSUrlRequest in objective c.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSURL Encoding in ObjC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748981/nsurl-encoding-in-objc)

Comment: Use POST instead, especially if you have passwords or username

Comment: @meda is right here, your user credentials will travel in clear text, stay in proxy logs / web servers / ..... You should be considering using POST over https

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
NSString *myRequestString = @"http://ww.a.com/Account/CheckValidUser?username=abc&password=abc123#"
NSString *requestStr = [myRequestString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Encode your string with NSUTF8StringEncoding